# Can I get back from POP!_OS to focal fossa?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 20.04

After testing the Pop theme via their PPA, I made a distribution upgrade from Focal Fossa to Pop!_OS by mistake. I did not realize that installing the System76 PPA meant that the system would try to "upgrade" from Ubuntu to Pop!_OS...

Is there a way to get back to Ubuntu Focal Fossa without re-installing the OS?

The file `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks "normal":

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal universe restricted multiverse main
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security restricted universe multiverse main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates restricted universe multiverse main
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports restricted universe multiverse main
```

But there is another file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` called `pop-default-settings` which explicitly references pop:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-system76-pop
Pin-Priority: 1001

Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-system76-proposed
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

Comment: You can use `ppa-purge`. But that won't guarantee returning back to original state. To use `ppa-purge`, run `sudo apt install ppa-purge; sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop`.

Comment: Thank you. I have downloaded an ISO but I can't find the sources.list file in there. Also, where must I put it once I found it?

Comment: Thanks Kulfy. I did that already but POP is installed already so it is too late.

Comment: Oh sorry forget about that.I was wrong.You don't need the ISO . Just delete the PPA file from ```/etc/apt/sources.d``` directory.It should be something like this ```/etc/apt/system76-pop.list```.Then run ```sudo apt update```.After that no program will be downloaded from the system76 repo.

Comment: I updated my question to reflect the fact that sources.list looks normal.

Answer (score 3):

Install the `ppa-purge` tool. It removes a package and reverts back to original packages. The `pop-default-settings`file in `/etc/apt/preferences.d` is a left over that does not have any function anymore because the PPA to which the preference applies is gone.

Comment: I have purged the ppa immediately, but I had done the upgrade alreday so it was too late...

Comment: @JulienLarena How did you purge PPA? There are many ways to purge PPA and PPA with packages.

Comment: I did sudo ppa-purge ppa:system76/pop

Comment: @JulienLarena Did you run this after removing PPA from sources.list.d?

Comment: In sources.list.d I have two files system76-ubuntu-pop-focal.list and system76-ubuntu-pop-focal.list.save but they are both empty.

Comment: These are leftovers that are not removed by removing the PPA. They are harmless and you could remove them.